# ui-sortable auto scrolls to the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Okay i have the following list:

```
                <ul  class="list-group gutter list-group-lg list-group-sp" ui-sortable="" ng-model="academyModules">
                    <li class="list-group-item module"  style="padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;" ng-repeat="module in academyModules" draggable="true">
                        <div class="clear" ng-if="module.module.module_type_id != null">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-10">
                                <button class="btn btn-s-xs btn-rounded m-r-lg" ng-class="module.module_type.color || module.module.module_type.color"
                                        style="padding:  2px 10px; min-width: 90px;">{{module.module_type.name || module.module.module_type.name}}
                                </button>
                                <span class="text text-muted">Modul</span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-md pull-right no-padder" ng-really-message="Er du sikker du vil slette modulet?" ng-really-click="deleteModule($index, module);">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times text-danger text"></i></a>
                            </span>
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-11">
                                <div class="input-group m-b">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="changeModule(module)" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#modal_select_module" style="font-size: 10px;"
                                                type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Skift modul
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /btn-group -->
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{module.module.name}}" style="height: 27px" disabled="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear" ng-if="module.module.module_type_id == null">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-10">
                                <button class="btn btn-s-xs btn-rounded m-r-lg bg-grey"
                                        style="padding:  2px 10px; min-width: 90px;">Kursus
                                </button>
                                <span class="text text-muted">Modul</span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-md pull-right no-padder" title="" ng-really-message="Er du sikker du vil slette kurset?" ng-really-click="deleteCourse($index, module);"><i
                                        class="fa fa-times text-danger text"></i></a>
                            </span>
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-11">
                                <div class="input-group m-b">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="changeCourse(module)" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#modal_select_module" style="font-size: 10px;"
                                                type="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Ret kursus
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /btn-group -->
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{module.name}}" style="height: 27px" disabled="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

This produces a list that looks something like this:

[image]

Now this works fine when there are few items however when the list is big enough and there scroll the drag and drop messes up. when i pick up an item on the middle of the page it always scrolls to the bottom and it is hard to get it to the top again!

Has anyone tried this before or know a way to fix it?

Comment: so you are having trouble scrolling up, why not use jquery scroll to top. an example here http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/scroll-to-top/scrolltotop.html

Comment: @AlexNewbie The issue only occours when i try to drag an item. the item goes completely out of control as soon as i got abit down on the page no matter where i select the item from